# Why does Python throw 'ImportError' for 'mediapipe' even though 'Requirement already satisfied' message appears when installing it using pip?

Tags: python, pip, importerror, mediapipe

I am currently running Python 3.7.9 64-bit on a Windows 10 operating system and using VS code. I am attempting to install and use the mediapipe package in my Python environment. When I run python -m pip install mediapipe in my terminal, it says "Requirement already satisfied," indicating that the package has been successfully installed.

However, when I try to import mediapipe in my Python script using import mediapipe as mp, I receive the following error message: "ImportError: cannot import name 'mediapipe' from 'mediapipe'" and Pylance reports the error "Import 'mediapipe' could not be resolved." (yellow squigly lines)

I have successfully installed other Python packages in this environment, so I assume that the path is correct. I have also tried reinstalling pip and updating my system packages, but the issue persists.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If any aditional information or screenshots are needed please let me know.

After researching the issue, I discovered that the issue could be related to my Python version. I was using the latest version at the time, so I downgraded to Python 3.7.9, which is listed as a compatible version on the mediapipe documentation.

After downgrading my Python version, I attempted to install mediapipe using pip install mediapipe again. The installation was successful, with no errors or warnings reported. However, when I tried to import mediapipe in my Python script using import mediapipe as mp, I received the error message saying that the package could not be found.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This import error normally means you are using a different python binary as opposed to the one that's associated with your ```python -m pip install mediapipe```.  Check whether VSCode is using the same python.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply.

I've tried python -m pip show mediapipe that gives "Location: c:\users\gebruiker\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages"

python where python gives "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'where': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Both give python37 if that is what you mean. I'm not realy sure what im looking for to be honest.

Comment: You should include that in your post and not in the comments.  Also, which python does VS Code use?

Comment: py -0 gives: 
" -V:3.11 *        Python 3.11 (64-bit), 
 -V:3.7           Python 3.7 (64-bit)"

I do think that it might still be on 3.11 indicated by the * ? I did ctrl+shift+p -> python select interpreter -> click python 3.7.9

Comment: Instead of using the usual method of selecting it through the command palette, I clicked on the Python version displayed in the top right corner of my screen and changed it from there. After restarting, I observed that my change had gone through successfully. Although the yellow squiggly lines persisted, my code ran without errors, leading me to believe that the interpreter version was updated correctly. Thanks for your time and help :)